# Quickly resize picture in PowerPoint to full slide size

Tags: resize, powerpoint

Anyone know a way to resize a picture in PowerPoint to full slide size that is quicker than moving and resizing by dragging? I'm thinking something like 'Fit to Page' with tables and printing in Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, you could write a macro like this

```
Public Sub cFitImage()

Dim srSelection As ShapeRange
Set srSelection = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

Dim sObjet As Shape
For Each sObjet In srSelection

    iOldHeight = sObjet.Height
    iOldWidth = sObjet.Width

    With Application.ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup

        If (iOldHeight / iOldWidth) > (.SlideHeight / .SlideWidth) Then
            sObjet.Height = .SlideHeight
            sObjet.Top = 0
            sObjet.Left = .SlideWidth / 2 - sObjet.Width / 2
        Else
            sObjet.Width = .SlideWidth
            sObjet.Left = 0
            sObjet.Top = .SlideHeight / 2 - sObjet.Height / 2
        End If
    End With

Next sObjet

End Sub
```

And call it from a personalized button in the apprpriate ribon (images/format) with some images selected.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll give it a go next time the need arises.

Comment: I've got a free add-in that'll do this and a number of other helpful tricks.  http://www.pptools.com/free/FAQ00002-THOR-The-Hammer.htm

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I'll take a look.